# ¿Por qué escribir una sentencia SQL en mayúscula o minúscula no marca error?

Tags: sql

A través de los años he notado que al escribir una sentencia SQL (por lo menos en los manejadores que más uso como SQL Server o SQL Developer) funciona de la misma forma si las escribes en mayúsculas como en minúsculas, tanto para las palabras reservadas como nombres de tablas y columnas.

Por ejemplo, tomando como base la siguiente sentencia SQL:

```
SELECT 
    A.ColumnaA, A.ColumnaB, B.ColumnaC
FROM TablaA AS A
    INNER JOIN TablaB B
        ON A.ColumnaA = B.ColumnaA
WHERE B.ColumnaB = 123
AND A.ColumnaC = 'ABC'
```

Si se escribe en minúsculas:

```
select 
    a.columnaa, a.columnab, b.columnac
from tablaa as a
    inner join tablab b
        on a.columnaa = b.columnaa
where b.columnab = 123
and a.columnac = 'abc'
```

O si se escribe en mayúsculas:

```
SELECT 
    A.COLUMNAA, A.COLUMNAB, B.COLUMNAC
FROM TABLAA AS A
    INNER JOIN TABLAB B
        ON A.COLUMNAA = B.COLUMNAA
WHERE B.COLUMNAB = 123
AND A.COLUMNAC = 'ABC'
```

No se genera ningún error, a diferencia de otros lenguajes que son totalmente restrictivos tanto para el uso de palabras reservadas como para nombres de variables.

No obstante, lo ideal es siempre escribir las palabras reservadas en mayúsculas y dejando los nombres de tablas o columnas a consideración del programador.

Incluso, al hacer uso del *plugin* **[Poor Man's T-SQL Formatter](http://www.architectshack.com/PoorMansTSqlFormatter.ashx)** para [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) da un formato a las palabras reservadas poniéndolas en mayúsculas e identa el *query* realizado (*un plugin maravilloso*).

Aunque el manejador no marque ningún error en el uso de mayúsuculas o minúsculas, me surgen principalmente dos dudas:

1. ¿Por qué escribir una sentencia SQL en mayúscula o minúscula no marca error?
2. ¿Por qué se prefiere o se recomienda hacer uso de las mayúsculas?

Comment: Plugin instalado exitosamente en Notepad++, conoces un shorcut para "Format T-SQL code" ?

Comment: Mmm, no @Goerman no conozco alguno, es posible que en la documentación indiquen algo, sin embargo, si logras notar en el menú de *plugins* de Notepad++ no dice nada :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**¿Por qué escribir una sentencia SQL en mayúscula o minúscula no marca error?**

Hay lenguajes de programación que distinguen entre mayúsculas y minúsculas (*case sensitive* o "sensibles a la caja"), y otros que no distinguen (*case insensitive*).

SQL es un lenguaje que no distingue entre mayúsculas o minúsculas (*case insensitive*, o no es "sensible a la caja") para las palabras reservadas. Por eso cuando se analiza la sentencia, no se lanza ningún error. Por ejemplo, no importa escribir `SELECT` o `select` o `sELect`, todas se interpretarán igual.

Es importante destacar la parte de "*para las palabras reservadas*" porque dependiendo del motor de base de datos que se use, el sistema operativo en el que se encuentre la base de datos, o del formato que se le dé a la consulta, sí que podría haber diferencias en los nombres de tablas o columnas. Por ejemplo:

- En algunas plataformas, en MySQL el uso de mayúsculas/minúsculas en los nombres de tablas debe ser consistente dentro de la misma sentencia o se producirá un fallo ([fuente](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)). La siguiente sentencia mostraría un error:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM personas WHERE PERSONAS.nombre = 'Juan'
  ```
- En MySQL, los nombres de las bases de datos y las tablas distinguen entre mayúsculas y minúsculas en sistemas operativos que hace esa distinción. Eso se debe a que están asociados a directorios/archivos del sistema de ficheros ([fuente](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/extensions-to-ansi.html)).
- En Oracle, se puede forzar que los nombres de tablas y columnas sean *case sensitive* si se ponen entre comillas dobles ([fuente Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129) y [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7425931/3695983)). Así estas dos sentencias serían diferentes:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM personas WHERE Nombre = 'Juan'
  SELECT * FROM "Personas" WHERE "nombre" = 'Juan'
  ```

**¿Por qué se prefiere o se recomienda hacer uso de las mayúsculas?**

Es una manera de diferenciar las palabras reservadas de las que no lo son, facilitando la identificación de los nombres de tablas, columnas, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Que las palabras reservadas sean validas tanto en minúscula como en mayúscula fue una decisión al desarrollar el estándar de sql, y todas las bases de datos que se basan en sql así lo implementa, por lo menos todas las que yo conozco.

En cambio para los nombres de tablas y columnas, no siempre es así, aunque depende específicamente de cada base de datos, la mayoría de de bases de datos de sql tienen una opción que permite escoger si estos nombres se han de tratar de forma distinta según el tipo de letra. Por ejemplo para sistemas windows la opción por defecto es que no afecte si es mayúscula o minúscula, en cambio en sistemas linux la opción por defecto es que si que haga diferencia entre mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Otro aspecto que marca el estándar de sql es que cuando se utilizan comillas para delimitar los nombres de tablas y columnas, se indica que en ese nombre en particular se debe diferenciar entre minúsculas y mayúsculas.

Por ejemplo con:

```
CREATE TABLE "TaBlA"
```

se especifica que el nombre de la tabla tiene que ser exactamente "TaBlA" no puede ser ni "tabla", ni "TABLA" ni cualquier combinación que no sea como la especificada, aunque es posible que en bases de datos especificas esta característica no este implementada, como ejemplo esta opción si que esta implementada en PostgreSQL, pero no en mySQL.

En cuanto a lo de usar mayúsculas para las palabras reservadas es simplemente un convención, que facilita identificarlas al leer una sentencia de sql y separar las palabras reservadas de los nombres.

[Parte de la versión ANSI99 de sql que habla sobre palabras clave y nombres.](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-99/sql-language-elements/)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, ¿existe alguna fuente oficial de la cual hayas obtenido esta información?

Comment: Creo que la especificación de sql no esta disponible de forma abierta, pero me parece que mariadb ofrece parte de la versión 99, aunque es algo vieja la busco y incluiré algún enlace aunque probablemente estarán en ingles.

Comment: Realicé el ejercicio que me comentas para SQL Server y es falso, puedo llamar al nombre del objeto de diferentes formas declarándolo con comillas. Ejemplo en [Rextester](http://rextester.com/SLGIH10221)

Comment: Esta característica depende de la implementación de cada base de datos, es posible que haya bases de datos que no lo implementen de esta manera, desconozco el caso especifico de SQL SERVER.

Comment: Vale ntp, entonces, ¿la respuesta que pusiste para qué manejadores aplicaría?